# How do you run WSL2 after it's already been installed?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 several months ago, did a quick "hello world" on the shell and then didn't use it after that.

How do I run it now that it's already been installed?

I can't find it on the menu or in the PATH.

I tried Googling but every article out there takes me to the beginning of the installation process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wsl.exe` executable should run the default distribution, and you can list them using `wsl -l [-v]` from PowerShell or cmd.

In addition, most distributions install a launcher such as ubuntu.exe, ubuntu2004.exe or opensuse.exe.  Try searching your Start Menu for "Ubuntu" or whatever distro you think you might have installed.

Comment: I'd also recommend installing Windows Terminal (www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701), as (by default) it will detect any WSL installations and automatically create a launch option for each one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, the WSL gets installed but it is like an under-the-hood upgrade, nothing much to see until you, as NotTheDroids mentioned getting Windows Terminal is probably the closest this to command prompt, but you can do classic Windows commands, but also classic linux commands: LS, PWD, ect...

But you can also go to the Windows Store and for instance install Ubuntu, and it will put a launcher icon after install.

Microsoft WSL is actually really interesting. You can do source compiling after installing DEV Essentials with Ubuntu, compile source, and then save it in a Windows directory from command line, then when you go back to Windows GUI, the files you compiled with Linux are sitting there right in your regular Windows directory folders.

They are starting to do some crazy stuff with our Operating Systems, Virtualization, etc...

I hope I helped a tad-bit.

Wayne

Comment: From the OP's question, it does sound like they installed a full distro (note that they did "Hello, World" in the shell), so I think this is more a matter of them just not knowing how to find the launcher (or perhaps even not knowing which distro they installed) months later..